# Can consume Kafka messages in console but not with Python library?

Tags: python, linux, apache-kafka, message-queue, kafka-consumer-api

I'm doing things locally on my laptop, and trying to read a topic 'test' from a remote server 'xxxxx'.
When using the console, I launch zookeeper, Kafka and then the consumer:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server xxxxx:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

And the messages will display in the console.
But when using Python library as follow, I see nothing:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

server = {'server': 'xxxxx:9092', 'topic': 'test'}

# To consume latest messages and auto-commit offsets
consumer = KafkaConsumer(server['topic'],
                         group_id='my-group',
                         bootstrap_servers=server['server'])

for message in consumer:
    # message value and key are raw bytes -- decode if necessary!
    # e.g., for unicode: `message.value.decode('utf-8')`
    print("%s:%d:%d: key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.partition,
                                         message.offset, message.key,
                                         message.value))
```

I can also successfully send messages locally from Kafka in console to Python Kafka consumer, the problem only happens when trying to consume remote messages.
Also the connection seems well established to the remote server (it can see me), but nothing is received unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is using another library, Confluent Kafka Python, and this library worked out of the box just by configuring the server IP and the name of the topic to listen to

Edit: here is the solution I implemented:

I thought Avro library was just to read Avro files, but it actually solved the problem of decoding Kafka messages, as follow: I first import the libraries and give the schema file as a parameter and then create a function to decode the message into a dictionary, that I can use in the consumer loop.

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError
from avro.io import DatumReader, BinaryDecoder
import avro.schema

schema = avro.schema.Parse(open("data_sources/EventRecord.avsc").read())
reader = DatumReader(schema)

def decode(msg_value):
    message_bytes = io.BytesIO(msg_value)
    decoder = BinaryDecoder(message_bytes)
    event_dict = reader.read(decoder)
    return event_dict

c = Consumer()
c.subscribe(topic)
running = True
while running:
    msg = c.poll()
    if not msg.error():
        msg_value = msg.value()
        event_dict = decode(msg_value)
        print(event_dict)
    elif msg.error().code() != KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
        print(msg.error())
        running = False
```